# How to create a new System.Xml.Linq.XElement with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, system.xml

I want to create an XML DOM programmatically using the **System.Xml.Linq** objects. I'd rather **not** parse a string or load a file from disk to create the DOM. In C# this is easy enough, but trying to do this in PowerShell does not seem possible.

**Option 1**: Doesn't work

```
$xlinq = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
$el = new-Object System.Xml.Linq.XElement "foo"
```

This gives the following error:

```
new-Object : Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "foo",
 for "XElement" to type "System.Xml.Linq.XElement": "Cannot convert value "foo" to
 type "System.Xml.Linq.XElement". Error: "Data at the root level is invalid. 
 Line 1, position 1.""
```

**Option 2:** Doesn't work

```
$xlinq = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
$xname = New-Object System.Xml.Linq.XName "foo"
$el = new-Object System.Xml.Linq.XElement $xname
```

It gives this error:

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Xml.Linq.XName.
```

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) "XName does not contain any public constructors. Instead, this class provides an implicit conversion from String that allows you to create an XName."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"XName does not contain any public constructors. Instead, this class provides an implicit conversion from String that allows you to create an XName."
```

Base on this you can cast `String` to `XName`:

```
$xname = [System.Xml.Linq.XName]"foo"

$xname.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     XName                                    System.Object
```

then:

```
$el = new-Object System.Xml.Linq.XElement $xname
$el


FirstAttribute :
HasAttributes  : False
HasElements    : False
IsEmpty        : True
LastAttribute  :
Name           : foo
NodeType       : Element
Value          :
FirstNode      :
LastNode       :
NextNode       :
PreviousNode   :
BaseUri        :
Document       :
Parent         :
LineNumber     : 0
LinePosition   : 0
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work too:

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse("<foo/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed your doing wrong is [System.Xml.Linq.XElement] has some custom instance so drop New- Object

```
$el = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new ([System.Xml.Linq.XName]"foo")
```

Everything in this namespace is created without New- Object in powershell.

Comment: Note the `::new()` syntax is for powershell 5 and higher.